# WPF, how to change RenderOrigin & keep location?

Tags: wpf

I would like to know please how to change RenderOrigin of an element without changing its location?
I've noticed that changing the RenderOrigin will affect element location, specially if it was rotated!

How can I calculate the delta X, delta Y between the element location before and after changing the RenderOrigin  ?

Answer (score 2):

Changing `RenderTransformOrigin` changes the origin of any `RenderTransform` applied to an object.  The object might appear to move around if you don't pick the centre point of the object (i.e. `0.5,0.5`).  Assuming you mean `RenderTransformOrigin`, try `0.5,0.5`, which means rotations and scale operations will be applied around the centre.

Does that help?

Comment: I need to use any RenderTransformOrigin value, and keep the object location unchanged, by adding the location shift delta,

Comment: You could add a `TranslateTransform` as the RenderTransform, or if you already have a transform, put the existing one and an additional TranslateTransform in a TransformGroup ?